# Error with java bitwise OR

Tags: java, int, bit-manipulation

Variable **intVar** is primitive int, **bb[]** is byte array {0x02,0xF7,0x8B,0xF9};

```
  intVar = bb[0];
  //intVar = 00000002    
  intVar <<= 8;
  //intVar = 00000200
  intVar |= bb[1];
  //intvar = fffffff7
```

Why????

Comment: That is Java's funny "negative" bytes at work. F7 becomes a negative integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is sign extension. Use:

```
  intVar = 0xFF & bb[0];
  //intVar = 00000002    
  intVar <<= 8;
  //intVar = 00000200
  intVar |= 0xFF & bb[1];
  // intVar = 000002F7
```

Using a negative byte (java bytes are signed) as int results in a negative int, and because java uses two's complement all leading bits will be 1. Anding that with 0xFF will get you the byte you had in the lowest 8 bits and 24 leading 0s.

Comment: The reason is sign *extension.*